# Not getting access token after authentication and callback code to use elance-api

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am trying to setup a node.js application to use the Elance API using OAuth2.0 I am using passport.js to connect to the elance api and so far am able to get the code properly. Before using the api methods, but not getting the access token.

have also tried it building strategy but wont get the access token to connect through the user profile

I have also tried the same from php but it also get sucked after getting  the call back code

This is the error I am getting via strategy:

```
failed to fetch user profile 
(status: 401 data: {"errors": [{"code":"missing_token","description": "Access token is required for this service"}]})
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be great if you posted some code of the strategy you are building. Looks like the exchange of code for token is not working. Is the project on GitHub?

Comment: The project: https://github.com/SumitBisht/passport-elance
Is it possible that the API itself is not functioning properly?